# Excell cell value is not read as Number?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add the data in the two cells of the excel sheet but even if the excel cell is of the type number it does not add up the cells. It seems that there is space infornt of the number that it does not add....image is below.
Is there a vba code to remove this space from each of the cell if its presesnt.[image]

I have exported the excel from a pdf.

Comment: Take a look at `Trim`. Either the VBA or Excel version.

Comment: if it is an non-breaking space issue, using `Right(D2,1)` will extract the number, assuming they are all 1 digit numbers. Or `Right(D2,Len(D2)-1)` for more than 1 digit numbers.

Comment: `=--TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(G7,CHAR(160),"")))` hopefully there is not other non printable characters that will not be cleaned or trimmed.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I need someone to come `Trim(Clean(Substitute...` my house! Is there a formula for that?! Hahahahaha ... But no `--` since right now the answer is def false!

Comment: @pnuts True and that is a great option.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman that depends on how much you are willing to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Excel will attempt to convert any value to a number if you apply an operator to it, and this conversion will handle spaces. So you can use `=A1*1` or `A1+0` to convert a value in A1 to a number, or something like this within a function `=SUM(IFERROR(A1*1,0))`.

That kind of implicit conversion automatically performs a `trim()`. You can also do this conversion explicitly by using the funciton `N()`, or [`NumberValue()` for newer versions of Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NUMBERVALUE-function-1b05c8cf-2bfa-4437-af70-596c7ea7d879). However, as others have pointed out, many characters won't be automatically handled and you may need to use `Substitute()` to remove them. For instance, `Substitute(A1,160,"")` for a [non-breaking space, a prime suspect because of its prevalence in html](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-spaces-and-nonprinting-characters-from-text-023f3a08-3d56-49e4-bf0c-fe5303222c9d). The `Clean()` function can give you a shortcut by doing this for a bunch of characters that are known to be problematic, but it's not comprehensive and you still need to add your own handling for a non-breaking space. You can find the ASCII code for any specific characters that are grieving you by using the `Code()` function... for instance `Code(Mid(A1,1,1))`

**Character Handling UDF**

The UDF below gives flexibility to the character handling approach by allowing multiple characters to be removed from every cell in a range, and produces a result that can be used as an argument. For example, `Sum(RemoveChar(A1:A5,160))` would remove all non-breaking spaces from the range being summed. Multiple characters can removed by being specified in either a range or array, for example `Sum(RemoveChar(A1:A5,B1:B3))` or `Sum(RemoveChar(A1:A5,{160,150}))`.

```
Function RemoveChar(R As Range, ParamArray ChVal() As Variant)
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim ResVals() As Variant
    ReDim ResVals(1 To R.Count)
    'Loop through range
    For j = 1 To R.Count
        x = R(j).Value2
        If x <> Empty Then
            'Try treating character argument as array
            'If that fails, then try treating as Range
            On Error Resume Next
            For i = 1 To UBound(ChVal(0))
                x = Replace(x, Chr(ChVal(0)(i)), "")
            Next
            If Err = 92 Then
                Err.Clear
                For Each Rng In ChVal(0)
                    x = Replace(x, Chr(Rng.Value2), "")
                Next
            End If
            Err.Raise (Err)
            On Error GoTo 0
            'If numeric then convert to number
            'so that numbers will be treated as such
            'when array is passed as an argument
            If IsNumeric(x) Then
                ResVals(j) = Val(x)
            Else
                ResVals(j) = x
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'Return array of type variant
    RemoveChar = ResVals
End Function
```

**Numeric Verifying UDF**

The drawback with replacing characters is that it's not comprehensive. If you want something that's more of a catch-all, then perhaps something like this.

```
Function GetNumValues(R As Range)
    Dim c, temp As String
    Dim NumVals() As Double
    ReDim NumVals(1 To R.Count)
    'Loop through range
    For j = 1 To R.Count
        'Loop through characters
        'Allow for initial short-circuit if already numeric
        For i = 1 To Len(R(j).Value2)
            c = Mid(R(j).Value2, i, 1)
            'If character is valid for number then include in temp string
            If IsNumeric(c) Or c = Application.DecimalSeparator Or c = Application.ThousandsSeparator Then
               temp = temp + c
            End If
        Next
        'Assign temp string to array of type double
        'Use Val() function to convert string to number
        NumVals(j) = Val(temp)
        'Reset temp string
        temp = Empty
    Next
    'Return array of type double
    GetNumValues = NumVals
End Function
```

Comment: that will not work for a non-breaking space - char(160) - as @pnuts points out in comment to OP. `=SUM(IFERROR(A1*1,0))` is dangerous as it potentially leaves out many values that could error without letting the user know.

Comment: Assumption was normal spaces or easily handled formatting. I guess to be safe it'd be best to through together some VBA as the OP asks about.

Comment: `=SUM(IFERROR(A1*1,0))` is a band-aid, but sometimes that's all you need.